# Using unmanaged dependencies in Scala on Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt

I have a Scala project that depends on some internal JAR's and SBT plugins placed in my own ivy/maven repository. My project layout is like this:

- **plugin-project**
- **jar-project** (uses SBT plugin from **plugin-project**)
- **war-project** (uses SBT plugin from **plugin-project** and depends on **jar-project**)

As I see it I have two problems

1. The Heroku project root lives in the **war-project** folder and thus when I push to Heroku the **plugin-project** and **jar-project** folders are not included and are thus not available for compilation.
2. The **war-project/project/plugins.sbt** resolves my plugin via my local ivy/maven repository which is also not available for Heroku when deploying.

For unmanaged Java/Maven dependencies the [Heroku guys solves a similar problem](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) by placing a repository locally within the Heroku project (in my case inside the **war-project** folder) and pointing to this in the **pom.xml**. Is something similar possible for SBT projects ? and if so how do get the line

```
addSbtPlugin("my.company" % "plugin-project" % "1.0")
```

used inside both the jar and web to resolve from a local place that's also available for Heroku under compilation ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a very similar solution to the Maven based solution you mentioned.

SBT (via ivy) has the concept of a FileSystem resolver, so you would just need to set up a repository directory in your project laid out in a pattern that matches the pattern of the resolver you set up in your SBT project.

like so

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("my-company-repo", file("company-repo"))
```

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Resolvers

Comment: this looks like the right way to go, in particular if one can get publish-local to push into this custom repository. I will test it tonight and get back